# Discord.js doesn't recognize my server members

Tags: discord, discord.js

I cannot iterate my server's members as `discordjs` seems to recognize only the bot but not the members :

```
guild.members.cache.filter(member => !member.user.bot).size; // return 0
```

I have two members on my server + 1 bot but `discordjs` still returns me 0 members.

Very strange.

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if you have intents enabled in the [discord dev portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications) on the current application. This is what they look like to switch on:
[image]

Comment: Thanks ! Indeed. This was the problem.